# Need assistance understanding the SQL statement in my code to get data from gridview of winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

```
private void UpdateEmployee(DataRow r, SqlConnection connection)
{
         int Emp_id = (int)r["Emp_id"];
         string Emp_name = (String)r["Emp_name"];
         int Dept_id = (int)r["Dept_id"];
         string Designation = (String)r["Designation"];
         string CNIC = (String)r["CNIC"];
         string Address = (String)r["Address"];
         string Contact = (String)r["Contact"];
         string DOB = (String)r["DOB"];
         string Gender = (String)r["Gender"];
         string Religion = (String)r["Religion"];
         string Nationality = (String)r["Nationality"];

         string sql = String.Format("Update Employee Set Emp_name=N'{1}',Dept_id={2},Designation=N'{3}', CNIC=N'{4}',Address=N'{5}',Contact=N'{6}',DOB=N'{7}',Gender=N'{8}',Religion=N'{9}',Nationality=N'{10}' Where Emp_id={0} ", Emp_id, Emp_name, Dept_id, Designation, CNIC, Address, Contact, DOB, Gender, Religion, Nationality);

         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
         command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Since I am new to Winforms, I was learning how to use combo box in gridview and get the data updated back to the database using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQN-a6BI8RE as reference.

But I can not understand the above query the author is using to get the data updated.

Mainly I would like to know what is the below part doing ?

```
int Emp_id = (int)r["Emp_id"];
string Emp_name = (String)r["Emp_name"];`
```

and what type of update `SqlCommand` is that? It is most like that the code above can be incorrect if possible can you advice if how to correct it.

Comment: Firstly, the video you are referring deals with `DataGridView` (`GridView` is a different control). Secondly, you have to be clear and comprehensive enough in your descriptions and don't refer to external resources (much less to a video, which nobody will watch). You cannot write a random code and expect anyone to understand what undefined variables mean. For example: `int Emp_id = (int)r`, etc. has no absolute meaning (it is clear what is doing, not why), but within the code being explained in that video. Please, put your ideas together and remember that basic learning is offtopic here.

Comment: I know no on will watch the video posted it just as a reference.I have some knowledge about sql statements.But the thing is i have never seen a sql statement like the one posted above so thats why i post the whole part making it easier to understand.if u can give guide me about it it would be great.

Comment: This is not exactly a SQL statement. In `String.Format` you are not inputting the resulting string (the SQL statement in that case), but a version admitting certain parameters. For example: "{1}", what means that there go the second associated variable, which is `Emp_name`. But this is not how you should learn and use this site, because you will not like the results: firstly, your learning will not be good (and the process will be unnecessarily frustrating and hard) and, secondly, you will be getting lots of negative responses here (e.g., downvotes, constant corrections, questions on hold).

Comment: Programming is not easy. If you are starting from almost the most basic level (SQL is useful for some C# implementations, but has nothing to do with C# or any other language to build applications), you would have to take things calmly and follow a proper learning process. Don't expect to know everything right away. SO is for experienced-enough programmers and that's why certain question are not welcome here. I recommend you to focus on your learning (the less you ask, the better), to maximise the huge amount of free online resources and to do lots of trial and error; rather than to ask here.